# Style and jQuery doesn't take effect when append from ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to use this code https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

To create Multi select Drop down.

The problem is: when I just type code in HTML `div` with no AJAX the drop down works fine but when I copy the same file and `.append()` or `.html()` to the `div` the formatting is off.

Note: I am appending the AJAX respond to the `div` (Class)

```
<div class= "tables">
    <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" multiple style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value="United States">United States</option>
     <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
     <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
     <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
     </select>
    </div>

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  $.ajax({
      url: "http://"+serverAdd+"/php_includes/sms_scaleSub.php",
      timeout: 5000,
      type: "GET",
      data: {"do" : "table"
    },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data_table) {
      //alert(data_table);
      var table = data_table;
      $('.tables').html(table);
    },

    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

      alert("ERROR: CONTACT YOUR ");
    }
  });
});
```

[image: demonstration]

Comment: what is api output? check on browser console for AJAX calls

Comment: Ajax call is correct since when I copy the result from (#table).text(data) and paste it in the html it work fine (refresh it)

Comment: @Bridge Your Ajax request is responding a JSON object (defined by dataType), but the call function is expecting a HTML result.